# Как подписаться на события типа show.bs.dropdown?

Tags: jquery, gwt, bootstrap, gwtquery

Есть проект на **GWT + Bootstrap**. Использую компонент [`Dropdown`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage). Хочу добавить обработчик на события появления и исчезания выпадающего меню. В документации сказано, что нужно использовать события `show.bs.dropdown, shown.bs.dropdown, hide.bs.dropdown, hidden.bs.dropdown`. И дан такой пример:

```
$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Пытаюсь по этому примеру подписаться на события. Разными способами из своего проекта (на  **Java**):

```
$(dropdownElement).bind("show.bs.dropdown", new Function() {
  @Override
  public boolean f(Event e) {
    System.out.println("show");
    return super.f(e);
  }
});
```

Или так:

```
private native void test(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element dropdownElement) /*-{
  $wnd.jQuery(dropdownElement).on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    alert('show')
  });
}-*/;
```

Или так:

```
dropdownElement.addEventListener('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    alert('show')
});
```

Но ничего не работает. Как же всё-таки подписаться на show/hide этого выпадающего меню?

Comment: нельзя подписаться на события в браузере серверными хэндлерами (исключая ajax)

Comment: @eicto, ваш вариант работает! Но не понял, к какому варианту относится коммент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По некоторым причинам (dowpdown всегда дочерний к `.button-group`) триггер [вызывается на parent](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L48) а не на сам элемент

вот так работает:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $out=$('#out');
   $('.dropdown-menu').parent().on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
       console.log(1);
       $('<div>').text('show').appendTo($out);
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RMZQ/