# Добавлять обработчик события ко всем новодобавленным элементам

Tags: jquery, javascript, bootstrap

У меня есть код (из предыдущего моего [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/272110)):

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('.dropdown-menu').parent().on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
      ...
   });
});
```

Он добавляет слушатель события только к уже существующим элементам, имеющим класс `dropdown-menu`. Но у меня элементы добавляются динамически в заранее неизвестный момент времени (зависит от многих факторов).

Как мне сделать, чтобы ко всем новодобавленным на страницу элементам класса `dropdown-menu` тоже добавлялся этот обработчик?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте on, событие нормально баблится:

```
$('body').on('show.bs.dropdown','.btn-group', function () {});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RMZQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Несколько вариантов.

1. На каждую функцию, добавляющую элемент вешать слушателя. Вариант не очень, если честно. Ну а уж если ты совсем хардкорный парень, то можно использовать setInterval() :D
2. Использовать MutationObserver.
3. Вешать слушателя на родителя, в которого добавляются эти элементы, а при событии смотреть e.target . Плюс в том, что нужные обработчики вешаются всего лишь на один элемент - родительский.

И просто ссылочка для общей инфы http://toster.ru/q/22322?_aa=press_anykey